# NPAPI plugin, removeChild from web page crashes Firefox4 & Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, c, plugins, npapi

I have a html page that opens a new window and loads a basic NPAPI written plugin that I opens a Wide Save dialog and then calls NPN_GetURL with a java-script function to close the window. Each time Firefox crashes and Chrome displays the plugin crashed. I'm not sure if the problem is HTML & JS or the plugin. I didn't find a whole lot when googling for other similar issues. Below is my page that loads the plugin and the javascript function "removePlugin" is called by the plugin. As for firefox no problems in 3.6 only in version 4

----Start

```
<html>
 <script language="javascript">
  function removePlugin()
   {
   var plgn = document.getElementById("myplugin1");
   document.getElementById("div1").removeChild(plgn);
   setTimeout('doClose()', 2000);
   }
 function doClose()
  {
  window.close();
  }
 </script>
 <body >
  <div id="div1">
   <embed type="application/x-My-Plugin" id="myplugin1"></embed>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

----End

----Start of Plugin code

```
#include "npapi.h"

//Prottype
LRESULT CALLBACK    PluginWindowProc  (HWND,UINT,WPARAM,LPARAM);

//Define
#define MY_MESSAGE      WM_USER + 1000

//Global
const char*     gInstanceLookupString = "instance";
WNDPROC         fDefaultWindowProc;

//Function:    NPP_SetWindow
NPError NPP_SetWindow(NPP       instance,
                      NPWindow *window)
{
    fDefaultWindowProc = (WNDPROC)SetWindowLongPtr((HWND)window->window,
                                                   GWL_WNDPROC,
                                                   (LONG)PluginWindowProc);
    SetProp(window->window,
            gInstanceLookupString,
            (HANDLE)instance);
    SendMessage(window->window,
                MY_MESSAGE,
                0,
                0);
    return NPERR_NO_ERROR;
}

//PluginWindowProc
LRESULT CALLBACK PluginWindowProc(HWND      hWnd,
                                  UINT      Msg,
                                  WPARAM    wParam,
                                  LPARAM    lParam)
{
OPENFILENAMEW       ofn;                                                                    //Fix.3a
WCHAR               szFile[512];                                //File name that appears in the Save Dialog box //Fix.3a
NPP                 instance;

    switch(Msg)
        {
        case MY_MESSAGE:
            instance = (NPP)GetProp(hWnd,
                                    gInstanceLookupString);
            //SAVE----------------------------------------
            memset(&ofn,
                   0x00,
                   sizeof(OPENFILENAMEW));

            memset(szFile,
                   0x00,
                   sizeof(szFile));
            _snwprintf_s(szFile,                                
                        _countof(szFile),
                        _countof(szFile),
                        L"Test.Txt");
            ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(OPENFILENAME);            
            ofn.lpstrFile = szFile;
            ofn.nMaxFile = _countof(szFile);
            ofn.Flags = OFN_PATHMUSTEXIST | OFN_HIDEREADONLY;

            GetSaveFileNameW(&ofn);


            //CLOSE---------------------------------------
            NPN_GetURL(instance,
                       "javascript:removePlugin(0);",
                       "_self");

            //--------------------------------------------
            break;
        default:
            CallWindowProc(fDefaultWindowProc,
                           hWnd,
                           Msg,
                           wParam,
                           lParam);
            break;
        }
    return 0;
    }

//Function:    NPP_Destroy
NPError NPP_Destroy(NPP instance,NPSavedData **save){return NPERR_NO_ERROR;}

//Function:    NPP_DestroyStream
NPError NPP_DestroyStream(NPP instance, NPStream *stream, NPError   reason){return NPERR_NO_ERROR;}

//Function:    NPP_HandleEvent
int16 NPP_HandleEvent(NPP instance,void* event){return 0;}

//Function:    NPP_Initialize
NPError NPP_Initialize(void){return NPERR_NO_ERROR;}

//Function:    NPP_New
NPError NPP_New(NPMIMEType pluginType,NPP instance, uint16 mode, int16 argc,char* argn[], char * argv[],NPSavedData* saved){return (NPERR_NO_ERROR);}

//Function: NPP_NewStream
NPError NPP_NewStream(NPP instance,NPMIMEType type, NPStream *stream, NPBool seekable, uint16 *stype){ return NPERR_NO_ERROR;}

//Function: NPP_Print
void NPP_Print(NPP instance, NPPrint *printInfo){}

//Function: NPP_Shutdown
void NPP_Shutdown(void){}

//Function: NPP_StreamAsFile
void NPP_StreamAsFile(NPP instance, NPStream *stream, const char *fname){}

//Function: NPP_URLNotify
void NPP_URLNotify(NPP instance, const char *url, NPReason reason, void *notifyData){}

//Function: NPP_Write
int32 NPP_Write(NPP instance, NPStream *stream, int32 offset, int32 len, void *buffer)        {return 0;}

//Function: NPP_WriteReady
int32 NPP_WriteReady(NPP instance, NPStream *stream){return 0;}
```

----End of Plugin code

Comment: You should provide the source of the plugin which is crashing.

Comment: a stack trace or crash log would also (or alternately) be very useful. What you've given us is not terribly helpful; I can tell you that I've done the same thing without difficulty, but since my plugin is undoubtedly different than yours that doesn't help you. Did you attach a debugger to find out if the crash is in your code or on firefox?

Comment: How do I get a stack trace or log? I have attached to firefox using Firebug and it seems that removeChild might be the problem, but I think it is more plugin related.

Comment: you get a stack trace with a C++ debugger, not a javascript debugger.  Also, you can do about:crashes to see the recent crash reports.

Comment: Well I went to the about:crashes and here is the crash report: https://crash-stats.mozilla.com/report/index/bp-d1e098dc-7ce3-46d0-b570-63a732110610   anyone know how to interpret this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is really difficult to tell for sure what is going on, but I can tell you that the approach you're taking has several other problems.  The first and foremost is that you *must not ever* block the main browser thread, which is what happens when you open a dialog in the main browser. Now, I realize that you might be okay (and some might even be under the delusion that others would be okay) with dialog locking up (no, not just preventing input, but actually locking up) the browser while your dialog is open, but in the cases of all current browsers that run the plugin out of process and *wouldn't* completely lock up while the dialog box is open the browser is liable to at the very least ask the user if they want to kill the plugin, if not just kill your plugin outright like Safari 5.1 would.

What you really need to do if you're going to use a dialog is start another thread and put the dialog call on that, then call back into the browser (on the main thread! use NPN_PluginThreadAsyncCall) when you're done.

As to the crash log, from what it is saying you've somehow borked the browser's handle to the plugin, because it's crashing when it tries to call SetWindow on your plugin. You might want to consider tossing this barebones attempt at NPAPI and use something like [FireBreath](http://www.firebreath.org), where the tricky NPAPI bits have already been solved for you.

Comment: WOW, i thought I would never get any input on this. This code here is stripped down version, to attempt to find where the plugin fails at. I understand your point by not allowing the plugins main thread to be blocked so that it can be terminated in case something goes wrong. But the point here is that the Save Dialog wide version fails OR that removing the plugin from the web page causes problems in FF 4 but not in previous versions.

Comment: no, you don't understand my point about not blocking the main thread.  The point is not so that it can be terminated -- it will be terminated if you block the thread. You must *never* block the main thread or some browsers *will terminate your plugin*. Others will ask the user if they want to terminate your plugin.

Comment: Next point is to reread the last paragraph in my answer; I realize that it's only happening in FF4, but FF4 now has out of process plugins which changes things. Something you're doing is messing up the browser's handle to you -- that may or may not be caused by the save dialog thing, but whatever it is it's something you're doing weird, because I don't have the problem with other plugins I use.